# Assigning border values to a chessboard that was constructed via a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, enums, grid

I am creating a Chess game for a homework assignment and I am having some problems in creating the grid. I have searched around but have been unable to find what I am specifically looking for.

I have successfully created my Chessboard and chess pieces, however I need to label the grid with two borders: a horizontal line of text (A to H) and a vertical line (8 to 1). While I have been able to place the horizontal border, I am unable to get the vertical border to line up with the appropriate rows of the chessboard. I would upload a picture, but I currently do have enough reputation points yet. Please let me know if this would help, and I can work something out.

As you will see in the code, that I have created the grid using a 2D array, with the pieces assigned via an enum class. I was thinking of adding the values for the borders in the enum class and then placing them within the loop that assigns the chess pieces their position, however I don't feel that this is what my lecturer intends.

Any suggestions or advice will be greatly appreciated.

```
public class VirtualChess {

public enum Chessmen{
    WHITE_KING, 
    WHITE_QUEEN, 
    WHITE_ROOK, 
    WHITE_BISHOP, 
    WHITE_KNIGHT,
    WHITE_PAWN, 
    BLACK_KING, 
    BLACK_QUEEN, 
    BLACK_ROOK, 
    BLACK_BISHOP, 
    BLACK_KNIGHT, 
    BLACK_PAWN, 
    EMPTY
}

public static void printBoard (Chessmen [] [] chessboard){ //A method to print out chessboard
    System.out.println("\tA\tB\tC\tD\tE\tF\tG\tH"); //This the horizontal border of the grid
    System.out.println("1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8"); //This the vertical border of the grid. This is faulty.
    for(int i = 0; i < chessboard.length; i ++){ 
        for (int j = 0; j < chessboard.length; j ++){
            switch (chessboard [i] [j]){
            case WHITE_KING: System.out.print("\u2654" + "\t"); break; //This places the Unicode characters of the chess pieces
            case WHITE_QUEEN: System.out.print("\u2655"+ "\t"); break;
            case WHITE_ROOK: System.out.print("\u2656" + "\t"); break;
            case WHITE_BISHOP:  System.out.print("\u2657" + "\t"); break;
            case WHITE_KNIGHT: System.out.print("\u2658" + "\t"); break;
            case WHITE_PAWN: System.out.print("\u2659" + "\t"); break;
            case BLACK_KING: System.out.print("\u265A" + "\t"); break;
            case BLACK_QUEEN: System.out.print("\u265B" + "\t"); break;
            case BLACK_ROOK:  System.out.print("\u265C" + "\t"); break;
            case BLACK_BISHOP: System.out.print("\u265D" + "\t"); break;
            case BLACK_KNIGHT:  System.out.print("\u265E"+ "\t"); break;
            case BLACK_PAWN:  System.out.print("\u265F" + "\t"); break;
            default: System.out.print(" " + "\t"); break;         
            }
       }    

            System.out.println("");

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Chessmen[][] chessboard = new Chessmen[8][8];

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i ++){ //Making the 8 x 8 chessboard
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j ++){
            if ( (i >= 2 && i <= 5) && (j <= 7)){
                chessboard [i] [j] = Chessmen.EMPTY;        //Assigning the chess pieces their starting positions
            } else {

            chessboard [0] [0] = Chessmen.BLACK_ROOK;
            chessboard [0] [7] = Chessmen.BLACK_ROOK;
            chessboard [7] [0] = Chessmen.WHITE_ROOK;
            chessboard [7] [7] = Chessmen.WHITE_ROOK;

            chessboard [0] [1] = Chessmen.BLACK_KNIGHT;
            chessboard [0] [6] = Chessmen.BLACK_KNIGHT;
            chessboard [7] [1] = Chessmen.WHITE_KNIGHT;
            chessboard [7] [6] = Chessmen.WHITE_KNIGHT;

            chessboard [0] [2] = Chessmen.BLACK_BISHOP;
            chessboard [0] [5] = Chessmen.BLACK_BISHOP;
            chessboard [7] [2] = Chessmen.WHITE_BISHOP;
            chessboard [7] [5] = Chessmen.WHITE_BISHOP;

            chessboard [0] [3] = Chessmen.BLACK_QUEEN;
            chessboard [7] [3] = Chessmen.WHITE_QUEEN;

            chessboard [0] [4] = Chessmen.BLACK_KING;
            chessboard [7] [4] = Chessmen.WHITE_KING;

            chessboard [1] [0] = Chessmen.BLACK_PAWN;
            chessboard [1] [1] = Chessmen.BLACK_PAWN;
            chessboard [1] [2] = Chessmen.BLACK_PAWN;
            chessboard [1] [3] = Chessmen.BLACK_PAWN;
            chessboard [1] [4] = Chessmen.BLACK_PAWN;
            chessboard [1] [5] = Chessmen.BLACK_PAWN;
            chessboard [1] [6] = Chessmen.BLACK_PAWN;
            chessboard [1] [7] = Chessmen.BLACK_PAWN;

            chessboard [6] [0] = Chessmen.WHITE_PAWN;
            chessboard [6] [1] = Chessmen.WHITE_PAWN;
            chessboard [6] [2] = Chessmen.WHITE_PAWN;
            chessboard [6] [3] = Chessmen.WHITE_PAWN;
            chessboard [6] [4] = Chessmen.WHITE_PAWN;
            chessboard [6] [5] = Chessmen.WHITE_PAWN;
            chessboard [6] [6] = Chessmen.WHITE_PAWN;
            chessboard [6] [7] = Chessmen.WHITE_PAWN;
            }
        }
    } 
    printBoard(chessboard);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am doing the same task and the solution of labeling I've found is:

```
    System.out.println("\tA\tB\tC\tD\tE\tF\tG\tH");

      for(int i = 0; i < chessboard.length; i ++){ 

            System.out.print((i+1) + "\t");

      for (int j = 0; j < chessboard[0].length; j ++){
```

Comment: Thanks! I came up with something very similar. I just used an array to print the numbers, where you used "System.out.print((i+1) + "\t")"